# error: expected primary-expression before ‘if’

Tags: c++, macros, libxml2

here is my code, I don't know where is wrong near 'if', and what is "primary-expression" in c?

xml_parser.h

```
#define xpath(smth, exp) if (sizeof(*smth) == sizeof(xmlNode)) { xpath_node((xml_node_ptr)smth, exp); } else{ xpath_doc((xml_doc_ptr)smth, exp); }

xml_node_ptr *xpath_node(xml_node_ptr n, str exp);

xml_node_ptr *xpath_doc(xml_doc_ptr n, str exp);
```

xml_parser_test.cpp

```
TEST_F(XmlParserTest, xpath2) {
    xml_node_ptr n = xpath(d, "/html/body");
    xpath(n, "/div");
}
```

here is my output:

```
/home/roroco/Dropbox/rbs/ro_sites/c/xml_parser_test.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void XmlParserTest_xpath2_Test::TestBody()’:
/home/roroco/Dropbox/rbs/ro_sites/c/xml_parser.h:17:26: error: expected primary-expression before ‘if’
 #define xpath(smth, exp) if (sizeof(*smth) == sizeof(xmlNode)) { xpath_node((xml_node_ptr)smth, exp); } else{ xpath_doc((xml_doc_ptr)smth, exp); }
                          ^
/home/roroco/Dropbox/rbs/ro_sites/c/xml_parser_test.cpp:26:22: note: in expansion of macro ‘xpath’
     xml_node_ptr n = xpath(d, "/html/body");
                  ^
```

my full source is [here](https://gist.github.com/roroco/9122341b9aa933b2b1ca)

Comment: Looks like that macro could be a regular function just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is pretty much being expanded to

```
xml_node_ptr n = if (sizeof(*d) == sizeof(xmlNode)) { xpath_node((xml_node_ptr)d, "/html/body"); } else{ xpath_doc((xml_doc_ptr)d, "/html/body"); }
```

by the preprocessor. Pretty obvious that's wrong. To answer your second question, `primary-expression` is the expected non-terminal in the C++ grammar. The primary expression is something like arithmetic, function calls, etc.

Comment: can you tell me how to pass variable-type argument?

Comment: @nwaicaethi You're going to have to be more specific.

Comment: In my code `define xpath(smth, exp)`, `smth` maybe `xml_doc_ptr` or `xml_node_ptr`, when `xml_doc_ptr` run `xpath_doc`, when `xml_node_ptr` run `xpath_node`, how to implement it?

Comment: @nwaicaethi Basing decisions on types can be done with the `typeid` operator. Though a better solution is probably to refactor your code to use some sort of polymorphic solution. If that's possible, of course.

Comment: @nwaicaethi I find the solution, use `#define xpath(smth, exp) sizeof(*smth) == sizeof(xmlNode) ? xpath_node((xml_node_ptr) smth, exp) : xpath_doc((xml_doc_ptr) smth, exp)` instead of old